# KSQL: The server has encountered an incompatible entry in its log and cannot process further DDL statements

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Working on a bunch of containers with docker-compose: 5 kafka broker and 3 ksqlDB Stream. Unfortunalely all the KsqlDB server status are DEGRADED and I have the following message after every command:

> WARNING: The server has encountered an incompatible entry in its log and cannot process further DDL statements.
> This is most likely due to the service being rolled back to an earlier version.

I'm not anymore able to create a table or delete one.
Note that I didn't upgrade or downgrade anything.

All my researches on the subject are vains, can't see the same error message anywhere

Comment: If you've not pinned a specific image in your Compose file and pulled a new image, such as latest tag, then you did do an upgrade

Comment: Thanks. Even if it's an offline computer?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to build/pull ksql completely offline. You'd at least need a maven repository mirror